# Strange icons in newest phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have just updated phpMyAdmin on board my local development package (XAMPP) to newest version (`4.3.11.1`). I use exactly the same package both at home and at office. After launching it in my office, just after phpMyAdmin update, it turned out, that it displays strange icons across entire application.

This is how it looks at my home (seems correct):

[image]

And here is my office version:

[image]

At first I thought, that I made some mistake, and maybe there's a different version at office. But I compared both and it turns out, that not only version matches, but also folder contents are 100% same. There is no difference, Total Commander compare tool show 1065 files identical on both sides and 0 different).

Does anyone have any idea, what can be wrong or from where this difference comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web browser has a stale cache for these icons. Reloading the page (which is often accomplished by holding shift or ctrl while pressing the refresh button) should fix it; if not you can log out of phpMyAdmin, clear your browse cache, and refresh the page and that should clear it up.

Comment: I did forced refresh (no effect), but clearing browser cache was something, that I forgot. Thanks, that surely solved the problem. Good questions here (?): (1) From where did phpMyAdmin take such strange icons and (2) How it is possible, that exactly the same steps to update it did not require browser cache clear on my home computer (where all icons were fine from the very beginning)?

Comment: Those icons are used elsewhere within phpMyAdmin. I'm not sure why your home computer worked okay while the other one did not; there is some logic in phpMyAdmin to force the browser to refresh and perhaps it was triggered in one but not the other, or perhaps the cache expired automatically (either by time or because disk space reached some critical usage).