# Red question marks in phpMyAdmin upon upgrade

Tags: phpmyadmin

I recently updated my phpMyAdmin from 4.0 to 4.4 as per instructions provided here:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/update-phpmyadmin/

But I am getting red question marks beside database names. Hovering says "Database Operations". [image: phpMyAdmin red question marks]

Any idea what is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange icons in newest phpMyAdmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040988/strange-icons-in-newest-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 2):

Dont Panic, most times just an problem of your Browser. 
Please clear your Browser Cache, and Reload the PhpMyAdmin page.

**Chrome:**

- Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar
- Select Tools
- Select Clear browsing data Place checkmark on ‘Empty the cache’ and
  press ‘Clear browsing data’ button

Comment: Clearing cache works, but what does the red question mark mean? @ArneRie

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you use? I met same problem in IE11 and compatibility view helped.

Comment: Please use comments for this!